# Is there a way to bind assets once instead of with every command encoder?

Tags: ios, metal, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I'm rendering a vertex/frag shader with a compute kernel.

Every frame I am binding large assets (such as a 450MB texture) in the usual way:

```
computeEncoder.setTexture(highResTexture, index: 0)
computeEncoder.setBuffer(largeBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
...
renderEncoder.setVertexTexture(highResTexture, index: 0)
renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(largeBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
```

So that is close to 1GB in bandwidth for a single texture, and I have many more assets totaling a few hundred megs, so that is about 1.5GB that I bind for every frame.

Is there anyway to bind textures/buffers to the GPU once so that they would then be available in the kernel and vertex functions without binding every frame?

I could be wrong, but I thought something was introduced in the one of the last couple WWDCs so thought I would ask to make sure I'm not missing anything.

EDIT:

By simply binding a texture in the vertex function that I have already bound in the compute encoder it does indeed show more texture bandwidth used, even though I am not using it for the capture.

GPU Read Bandwidth:

- 6.3920 GiB/s without binding
- 7.1919 GiB/s with binding

Without binding the texture:
[image]

With binding the texture but not using it in any way:
[image]

Also, if it works as you describe, why does using multiple command encoders warn about wasted bandwidth? If I use more than one emitter, each with a separate encoder, even though they bind identical resources, I get the performance warning:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confused. Setting a texture to a command encoder doesn't consume bandwidth. Reading it or sampling it inside the shader does.

When you set a texture or any other buffer to an encoder, what happens is that driver just passes some small amount of metadata to the shader using some mechanism, likely some internal buffer that's not visible to you as the API user. It doesn't "load" the texture anywhere. There's an exception for buffers that are marked as `constant` address buffers in the shaders, because those *may* get pre-fetched by the GPU for better performance.

Another thing that happens is that the resource is made *resident*, meaning the GPU driver will map a range of addresses in the GPU addresses virtual memory table to point to the physical memory that stores the texture contents. This also does not consume memory, but it does consume available virtual address space. You *might* run out of virtual address space in some cases, but that's not a bandwidth issue.

Still, if you do have a **lot** of textures, you might be actually spending a lot of CPU time just encoding those `setTexture` commands. Instead, you can use argument buffers. If the hardware you are targeting supports argument buffers tier 2, you can put every texture in an argument buffer. This will require calling `useResource` on all of those textures, because the driver needs to know that you are going to use those textures to make them resident, so you will still spend CPU time encoding those commands. To avoid that, you can allocate all the textures from one or more heaps and call `useHeaps` on those heaps. This will make the whole heap resident, and you won't need to call `useResource` on individual resources. There are a bunch of WWDC talks on this topic, latest one being [Explore bindless rendering in Metal](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10286).

But again, to reiterate: nothing I mentioned here "wastes" bandwidth.

Update:

A very basic example of using argument buffers would be to use it like this.

```
let argumentDescriptor = MTLArgumentDescriptor()
argumentDescriptor.index = 0
argumentDescriptor.dataType = .texture
argumentDescriptor.textureType = .type2D

let argumentEncoder = MTLArgumentEncoder(arguments: [argumentDescriptor])

let argumentBuffer = device.makeBuffer(length: argumentEncoder.encodedLength, options: [.storageModeShared])

argumentEncoder.setArgumentBuffer(argumentBuffer, offset: 0)
argumentEncoder.setTexture(someTexture, index: 0)

commandEncoder.setBuffer(argumentBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder.useResource(someTexture, usage: .read)
```

And in the shader you would write a struct like this:

```
struct MyTexture 
{
    texture2d<float> texture [[ id(0) ]];
};
```

and then bind it like

```
device MyTexture& myTexture [[ buffer(0) ]]
```

and use it like any other struct. This is a very basic example and you can actually use reflection to create those `MTLArgumentEncoders` for you from functions and binding indices.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I guess I thought it was using bandwidth because I previously made two calls to the rendering pipeline for two emitters. I got a bandwidth warning in Metal diagnostics about wasted bandwidth. I've since combined them into a single call, but wanted to make sure there wasn't something more optimal. Thanks - yeah bindless textures is what I was thinking of. For completeness, could you show a bit of code (pseudo is fine) on how to use bindless?

Comment: I should note that residency is managed per encoder, so `useResource` or `useHeap` calls must be in all the encoders that might use the resource. I also advise against just trying to make everything resident. I suggest doing at least some bookkeeping to keep number of resources you make resident at bay. But yeah, if you have to make them resident, you have to make them resident, there's no other way around that. Shader validation layer is very helpful at finding residency errors, but without that layer, it can lead to very bizarre behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the example! But, I'm not sure if your reasoning is entirely correct based on what I am seeing. Can you please take a look at my Edit?

Comment: I take it then there is no single binding functionality that can then be used throughout the pipelines. Which seems like a missed opportunity because besides simplifying frame generation code (less code per frame), it would be more efficient on the CPU, and seems that it would be more difficult to waste bandwidth.

Comment: Hm, not sure how texture binding results in higher bandwidth. But I can definitely say that coalescing encoders warning warns you about wasting bandwidth on unnecessary load/stores. It basically says that you store the attachments and then load the same attachments in the next encoder, which means you could have used the first encoder all along. That means you are ending encoding somewhere and re-creating another encoder with the same descriptor.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely appears to be the case though which is the reason for posting. I have coalesced encoders but based on your reasoning, I really shouldn't need to. I just don't get why we can't bind once - I need them every frame all the time. Do you think the idea is worth filing with Feedback Assistant?

Comment: Well, this is expected. The commands may be similar or even identical. If you find yourself constantly having to encode identical comments, you might want to use Indirect command buffers.

Comment: I'm sorry but what are you saying is expected? Thanks I'll take a look at that.

Comment: Really the only thing that changes in my render commands is the parameters passed in as an argument buffer. So mostly identical but not identical; not sure if that makes a difference.